# Does "than private vehicles" only modify what closely precedes it?

Tags: grammar, structure

I was told that "than private vehicles" only modifies carbon emissions. I'm only comparing the per-capita carbon emissions of trains and cars, and not their capacities. Is this true?

> This is good for the environment since subway and tram trains have a
> much larger capacity and therefore much lower per-capita carbon
> emissions **than private vehicles.**

And for this version, I'm only comparing their capacities, not emissions. Is this true?

> This is good for the environment since subway and tram trains have a
> much larger capacity **than private vehicles** and therefore much
> lower per-capita carbon emissions.

I want to compare both carbon emissions and capacities of trains and cars. Does this version solve the problem?

> This is good for the environment because, **compared with private**
> **vehicles,** subway and tram trains have a much larger capacity and
> therefore much lower per-capita carbon emissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the sentences are already adequately expressing that. If you do want to use the second sentence, I would suggest you to use "to".

> This is good for the environment because, compared **to** private
> vehicles, subway and tram trains have a much larger capacity and
> therefore much lower per-capita carbon emissions.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about this version: this is good for the environment since subway and tram trains have a much larger capacity than private vehicles and therefore much lower per-capita carbon emissions? Does it still express what I want to express?

Comment: Just want to let you know that I've edited my question.

Comment: All are equivalent. All are expressing what is compared to the what other. the reason (capacity), the result(emission), All are equivalent.